How to Calculate EMAT for a System with 30% L1-D Hit Rate and 98% L2 Hit Rate?
I’m trying to calculate the Effective Memory Access Time (EMAT) for a system described in the following problem:
Problem Setup

The system uses Intel Ice Lake Client micro-architecture with multiple TLBs.
Page size: 4 KiB.
TLB structure:

L1-D TLB: 64 entries, access time = 1 ns.
L2 TLB: 2048 entries, access time = 5 ns.


Parameters:

Memory access time (( \Delta t_{mem} )) = 100 ns.
On a TLB miss, 4 additional memory accesses are required.


Hit rates:

L1-D TLB hit rate (( \rho_{TLB,L1-D} )) = 30%.
L2 TLB hit rate (( \rho_{TLB,L2} )) = 98%.



What to Calculate
The Effective Memory Access Time (EMAT), which combines the contributions of hits and misses across the two TLB levels and memory access.

My Attempt

EMAT Formula Setup:

If there’s an L1-D hit, EMAT is the L1-D access time.
If there’s an L1-D miss but an L2 hit, EMAT includes both TLB access times.
On a complete miss, include memory access time for additional loads.

Formula:
EMAT = (ρ_TLB,L1-D * Δt_TLB,L1-D) + 
       ((1 - ρ_TLB,L1-D) * (ρ_TLB,L2 * (Δt_TLB,L1-D + Δt_TLB,L2) + 
       (1 - ρ_TLB,L2) * (Δt_TLB,L1-D + Δt_TLB,L2 + 4 * Δt_mem)))


Plugging in Values:
EMAT = (0.30 * 1) + 
       (0.70 * (0.98 * (1 + 5) + 
       0.02 * (1 + 5 + 4 * 100)))


Stuck on Simplification:
I’m struggling to simplify this correctly and ensure the logic is accurate.



What I Need Help With

Is my formula for EMAT correct based on the problem setup?
How do I simplify the equation to get the final value?
Are there any mistakes in my interpretation of the hit/miss calculations?


Thanks in advance for your help!
